# IMobileServiceSyncTable Incremental PullAsync - No Results

Tags: c#, sqlite, azure, xamarin, offlineapps

I'm trying to use the incremental feature from the PullAsync method. My problem is: When i pass the queryId parameter to this function it returns no results. Without this parameter it works.

Test scenario: The local sqllite table is empty and the PullAsync method is executed for the first time.

Working:

```
await this.ISyncTable.PullAsync(null, query, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Not working:

```
 await this.ISyncTable.PullAsync(queryId, query, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

QueryId used in this example: "aa"

My two questions:

1. Why is this not working?
2. Should i generate a queryId for each individual query or can i use one queryId for all queries and renew the queryId every 7 days?

Comment: I found the problem for the first question: The UpdatedAt column in the server database was NULL. I thought first if no value is deposited the dataset is always fetched. Can you help me with my second question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When do an Incremental Sync, pull operations retrieve only records after the latest `updatedAt` timestamp. Besides, as for your second question, normally we create unique query name for each logical query, if different pull operations with same query name could overwrite the same incremental sync timestamp and then the queries would return incorrect results.

For detailed information about *Offline Data Sync in Azure Mobile Apps*, please refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync).